# I am looking for a description or datasheet of small chip on a computer motherboard. The text on the chip is: K4=6E 743

Tags: identification, components

I am trying to find the specifications for a chip marked K4=6E 743 as shown in the image.

The chip is on a motherboard.

[image]

Comment: Judging by the surrounding capacitors and inductor, I'd assume a DC-DC converter. Probably with internal switches, as I can't see anything associated with it that looks like a switch.

Comment: Thanks alot Hearth